# What is the name of the table where view modes are stored?

Tags: 8, nodes, hooks

We have 10 view modes that we created. When we run `drush @env cex sync` in our local we are able to export the config files related to these view modes such as `core.entity_view_mode.node.related.yml` (where related is the view mode).

Is there a database table where these View modes are stored? If so, what is the name of it?

We are not using [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) or [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels), just the out of the box View Modes from Core. We do not plan to add those modules.

Goal:

1. Find out what view modes are being used programmatically.
2. Delete all view modes that are not being used.

Definition of `not being used`:

1. `Article` content type has 3 custom view modes: `listing, minimum, related`
2. `Basic Page` content type has an Entity reference to `Article` pages where the `Article view mode = listing` under `Basic Page Default View Mode`.
3. Custom view modes `listing` and `minimum` are not being used. However, if we consider all content types (e.g. 10 more content types) then it will be a pain to have to go through one by one.

Comment: you say in definition - #2 "Article view mode = listing", then on #3 "listing and minimum are not being used.", can you review this please?

Comment: it seems like you know which view modes are not in use, so why don't you just delete them in the admin interface (/admin/structure/display-modes/view)?

Comment: @CesarMoore I have updated the questions goal and definition. We are looking for a programmatic way to figure out what is being used and what is not. Hopefully it is clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration is stored in the **config** table

```
mysql> describe config;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| collection | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| name       | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| data       | longblob     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This is an example query from the *umami demo profile*:

```
    mysql> select name from config where name like 'core.entity_view_display.node.article.%';
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| name                                                  |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| core.entity_view_display.node.article.card            |
| core.entity_view_display.node.article.card_common     |
| core.entity_view_display.node.article.card_common_alt |
| core.entity_view_display.node.article.default         |
| core.entity_view_display.node.article.full            |
| core.entity_view_display.node.article.rss             |
| core.entity_view_display.node.article.teaser          |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This is an answer to the original question: "What is the name of the table where view modes are stored?" ... "Is there a database table where these View modes are stored? If so, what is the name of it?"

Answer (score 3):

View modes are stored in the configuration entity `entity_view_mode` which you can load like any other entity:

```
$view_mode = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('entity_view_mode')
  ->load('node.teaser');
```

To load all view modes for the entity type `node`:

```
$view_modes = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('entity_view_mode')
  ->loadByProperties(['targetEntityType' => 'node']);
```

View modes don't store much data other than a label for the view mode name.

How a view mode is displayed for a specific content type is stored in a different entity:

```
$display = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('entity_view_display')
  ->load('node.article.teaser');
```

The usage depends on how you define what being used means. If you mean with not used that it is not configured in a content type, which you can query in the config entities mentioned before, this doesn't mean necessarily, that the view mode is not used anywhere. If you configure an entity to be displayed in a view mode, for example in a View or a entity reference field, and this view mode is not configured in the content type, then it fallbacks to the default view mode.

Comment: Just updated the question with definition of `not being used`

Comment: If this is only for the usage between referenced content types you could load all displays like in the last code example and check the field formatter settings of all reference fields. But this would be only one of many places where view modes can be used.